# Soap UI Test step result in the name of file where request and response is saved

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I have a Soap Project, where I want to save Request and response in txt format locally with the Test Step Result in the Name

```
    def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->
            suite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
                 kase.testStepList.each { step ->
                    if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
                     def reqFilePath = new File("${directoryToSave}/${suite.name}_${kase.name}_${step.name}_request${dt}.txt")   
                   def resFilePath = new File("${directoryToSave}/${suite.name}_${kase.name}_${step.name}_response${dt}.txt")  
                   saveToFile(reqFilePath, step.testRequest.requestContent)
                   saveToFile(resFilePath, step.testRequest.responseContent)
                                                                                } else {
                 log.info "Ignoring as the step type is not Soap request"
            }
```

Currently, I am using these line to save request and response .

Current

```
File Name - SuiteName.TestCase.TestStep_response.txt
```

Expected

```
File Name -SuiteName.TestCase.TestStep_response_TESTSTEPRESULT(PASS/FAIL)_Response.txt
```

Comment: @Rao please help

Comment: How are you running the tests? try with `testrunner`, it should be generated in the same format if you configure results directory.

Comment: I have a dedicated script to write request and response. I am not running using test runner . I would like to get it using context

Comment: I would suggest you try with testrunner and see. Because, it automatically saves.

Comment: @Rao just edited the code section , i would like to reuse this. and also this solution is also provided by you only :)